# In C++, how can I render city lights on the night side of the Earth with D3D9?

Tags: c++, directx, textures

What I'm doing to render some beautiful city lights on the night side of the Earth is to render a second sphere mesh on top of the Earth mesh, then I set the city lights texture on it with 200% ambient light so they become very bright, and make the alpha channel of the dds texture file transparent so the Earth texture can be seen behind on the original Earth mesh.

The result is this pretty nice effect:
http://s24.postimg.org/gpqg8a491/screenshot_2.png

This is the code for the mesh holding the lights texture:

```
        d3ddev->LightEnable(0, FALSE);
        d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_AMBIENT, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(200, 200, 200));
        d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);
        d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);
        d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_DESTALPHA);
        //d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAREF, (DWORD)0x0000008f);
        d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHATESTENABLE, FALSE);
        d3ddev->SetTexture(0, earth_lights);
```

However the bad thing is that the lights also show in the day side, always, and that's pretty bad.

How can I achieve a similar result but with the lights not showing in the day side? Texture blending? Shaders?

Comment: What has your research turned up so far?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, Well, I experimented with some texture blendings and stages but all it seems to be able to do is,,, well, blend both textures together, but I can't make only the lights to become bright on one texture without turning the whole planet into a light bulb

Comment: Seems like you have quite a bit more research to do, then! Can you cite the papers you read and explain why they did not help you to solve this?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit. Indeed, I still have a lot of research to do, but I thought someone could give me a hand in this and spare me a lot of hours of more research, like,,, someone who knows enough to point me into the right track, maybe even with some code examples and stuff.
Cite the papers, well, too many to post here, pretty much all I can find googling about.

Comment: Did you try a [_library_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library#Research_libraries)? You can't get by with only Google!

Comment: Never underestimate the Internet, buddy, you'd be surprised of what you can find in there ;)

Comment: The lights of a city should be too dim to see on the day side, no?  Maybe you need a wider range of brightness.